# crm 2016 javaScript Get lookup name by Fetch

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

i try to get a Lookup field from Entity (not matter the type)
with fetchXml but i don't get in the result the text of the lookup;

for example (account entity, owner field):

```
var fetchXml = "<fetch mapping='logical'>" +
            "<entity name='account'>" +
                "<all-attributes />" +
                "<filter>" +
                    "<condition attribute='accountid' operator='eq' value='{475B158C-541C-E511-80D3-3863BB347BA8}' />" +
                "</filter>" +
            "</entity></fetch>";

var fetchResult = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Fetch(fetchXml);
var owner = fetchResult[0].attributes["ownerid"];
```

the result [**logicalName missing**]:

[image]

i found a solution to use linkEntity but it's not a good solution for me because i need a generic function

if i get the field directly from the form i get all the information:
**Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ownerid").getValue()[0]**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you're using **XrmServiceToolkit** and **CRM 2016**. I had this same problem with this combination of tools

I found that someone else (not me) had already reported and fixed this. Refer to [this bug](https://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/1862)

It seems like the XML being returned from CRM has changed to include 2 new nodes and that this is breaking the way the XrmServiceToolkit is reading the option set values.

The bug report includes a possible fix. I'm including it here for future reference

The original XrmServiceToolkit has this code

```
case "a:EntityReference":
    entRef = new xrmEntityReference();
    entRef.type = sType.replace('a:', '');
    var oChildNodes = tempNode.childNodes;
    entRef.id = getNodeText(oChildNodes[0]);
    entRef.logicalName = getNodeText(oChildNodes[1]);
    entRef.name = getNodeText(oChildNodes[2]);
    obj[sKey] = entRef;
    break;
```

You can see it is referring explicitly to `oChildNodes[0]`; `oChildNodes[1]`; and `oChildNodes[2]` - this is causing the bug you've encountered.

The updated code is:

```
case "a:EntityReference":
    entRef = new xrmEntityReference();
    entRef.type = sType.replace('a:', '');
    var oChildNodes = tempNode.childNodes;
    for (var n = 0; n < oChildNodes.length; n++) {
        var currentNodeName = oChildNodes[n].nodeName;
        switch (currentNodeName) {
            case "a:Id":
                entRef.id = getNodeText(oChildNodes[n]);
                break;
            case "a:Name":
                entRef.name = getNodeText(oChildNodes[n]);
                break;
            case "a:LogicalName":
                entRef.logicalName = getNodeText(oChildNodes[n]);
                break;
        }
    }
    obj[sKey] = entRef;
    break;
```

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot!!